# problem to configure public key on google audit email api

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

I need a help! I'm trying to use the google auditing API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit)
Im getting a problem to configure the public key on API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#example), receiving the following error:

```
The value of attribute &quot;value&quot; associated with an element type &quot;apps:property&quot; must not contain the
&#39;&lt;&#39; character.
```

Im following the documentation payload:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="<em>my public key in base64 here</em>"/>
</atom:entry>
```

One example of public key that i generated and encoded on base64:

```
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
```

If you check on base64 decode for example, you can see that its a complete public key...
Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message points that there is a non valid character being passed on the `"value"` attribute, in this case the `<>` characters are non valid within the value field, checking your example you are adding it like this:

```
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="<em>my public key in base64 here</em>"/>
```

Where the `"value=<em>my public key in base64 here</em>"` is being passed with the `"<>"` characters, even though the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/auth#upload_the_public_key) states that `"<em>"` and `"</em>"` is passed you can still just remove the tags and add the public key without them like this:

```
<apps:property name="publicKey" value="my public key in base64 here"/>
```

Comment: Removing the <em> worked!
After I had a problem with my key format. To solve this other problem, I had to use the GPG version 1.4, then it solved my problem and the API worked.

Thank you!